# Symbol mc70 encoding barcode data via TCP

Tags: python

I have a barcode scanner motorola symbol mc70, via TCP I am able to send data with this app

But instead of text it gives me something like this:

```
\x9d(\xe7\xae\xbc@\x94x\x0b\xa0*\xd8\x93\
```

How am I supposed to print it as normal word?

Comment: Could you tell us what the message should be ? If I translate it using `str(\x9d[...]` I get `\x9d(ç®¼@\x94x\x0b\xa0*Ø\x93`, is this normal ? Also, could you remove the trailling backslash, because it's the escape character, and it has nothing to escape, or add the missing characters...

Comment: This is some sample i made on friday. I think it say's "like_that" and i paste everything i think. On monday in work i will paste some more.

Comment: Is the protocol of communication proprietary ? Maybe does Motorola _crypt_ its data... Do you remember if the whole message was long or not ? Maybe what you've posted is just a header informing of the model of the product...

Comment: you can see my code, i dont know much about it, but when i scan other codes, message is completly different. I got this program for windows wich translate this into a keyboard stroke it's called ipwedge and the app i'm using on motorola is datawedge. i dont know if my code is good for reading this kind of stuff. But for me it's just something that only need to be translated. But thanks for your help man.

Comment: You're welcome! I wish I couls help, but I don't have enough data... You could maybe read the data sheet, or compare many message with the supposed carried message!

Comment: You were right man! Thanks a lot! Motorola actually crypt it's data :) i only need to switch of 1 option in device and it sends now clear text :) Thanks again :)

Comment: You're welcome :) you can mark your answer as the good answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to spirine i know now that motorola crypt it's data. Just needed to switch data wedge option in configuration of ipwedge in device